# Optimize a stored procedure that accepts table parameters as filters against a view

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization

I'm looking for an efficient way to filter a view with optional table parameters.

Examples are best so here is a sample situation:

```
-- database would contain a view that I want to be able to filter
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[MyView]
AS
BEGIN
     -- maybe 20-40 columns
    SELECT Column1, Column2, Column3, ...
END
```

I have user-defined table types like so:

```
-- single id table for joining purposes (passed from code)
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[SingleIdTable] AS TABLE (
    [Id] INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC) WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF));

-- double id table for joining purposes (passed from code)
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[DoubleIdTable] AS TABLE (
    [Id1] INT NOT NULL,
    [Id2] INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id1] ASC, [Id2] ASC) WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF));
```

And I want to create a stored procedure that basically looks like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[FilterMyView]
    @Parameter1 dbo.SingleIdTable READONLY, 
    @Parameter2 dbo.DoubleIdTable READONLY, 
    @Parameter3 dbo.SingleIdTable READONLY
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT *
    FROM MyView
    INNER-JOIN-IF-NOT-EMPTY @Parameter1 p1 ON p1.Id  = MyView.Column1 AND
    INNER-JOIN-IF-NOT-EMPTY @Parameter2 p2 ON p2.Id1 = MyView.Column5 AND
                                              p2.Id2 = MyView.Column6 AND
    INNER-JOIN-IF-NOT-EMPTY @Parameter3 p3 ON p3.Id  = MyView.Column8
END
```

Now I believe I can do this with `WHERE EXISTS` but I want to make sure that I am doing this in the most efficient way for the SQL engine. I've always personally felt that the `INNER JOIN` semantic creates the most optimized execution plans, but I don't actually know.

I also know that I can do this using dynamic SQL, but I always leave this as a last option.

Comment: And if your proc receive an XML as a parameter?

Comment: @Onaiggac That will never happen.

Comment: Any sort of "only join if not empty" is going to require to either use an exists check as a where predicate OR dynamic sql.

Comment: @test, see the Optional Tables section of http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html.